# Help needed to bypass Carrier EIM module for Ecobee

Tags: hvac, low-voltage

I have an ecobee thermostat that I want to install, but I discovered we have a carrier EIM module in place between our existing thermostat, and our HVAC unit. Here is a wire diagram of the existing setup.

[image: Existing Wiring]

Here are the ecobee terminals
[image: Ecobee terminals]

The free hanging blue, yellow, and brown wires are part of the bundle of wires in the wall, but are not connected on either end right now. I engaged with ecobee support, but they wanted to check my HVAC control board. I removed the front panel from my air handler and found all the wires, but it wasn't what they were looking for.

Is it possible that I can just bypass the EIM module by splicing the correct wires together..or do I need something more? Thanks for any help.

Inside HVAC

[image]

Wiring diagram on HVAC panel

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bypass it.

The ecobee will replace all the functions of the EIM.

The Independent Fan function- G

The Cooling function - Y

The Heat Pump function -O/B

If you have two stage cooling/heating connect those accordingly to ecobee.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, I'll give it a try soon. The only thing - I only have 5 wires coming to the thermostat but an extra W2 terminal that I think is for the Emergency Heat option on my thermostat, which I think activates a heat strip within the air handler? I have never used this mode before and thought it would be fine to ignore it for now.